# mutable reference problem with PyQt5 using lambda in slot

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a simple example `PyQt5` program below which creates two `QPushButtons` in a loop, one for each value in a list, `[ "foo", "bar" ]`

It sets the `clicked` slot to a lambda which prints the current list value.

It **should** print `"foo"` when the user clicks the `foo` button, and bring `"bar"` when the user clicks the `bar` button.

Instead, however, it prints `"bar"` when clicking either.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        for i in [ 'foo', 'bar' ]:
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(i)
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(i)) # print "foo" or "bar"
            layout.addWidget(btn)

qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app = App()
app.show()
sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

The issue I'm having (I presume) is that the value of `i` is reassigned on each iteration of the loop, so when the user clicks on the `"foo"` button, the lambda has a reference to `i`, which was subsequently set to `"bar"`.

As such, every time the user clicks a button, **both** `foo` and `bar` print `bar`.

I have tried using `copy.copy(i)` and `copy.deepcopy(i)`:

```
for i in [ 'foo', 'bar' ]:
    i = copy.deepcopy(i)
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(i)
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(i))
    layout.addWidget(btn)
```

Unfortunately that has no effect.

**Question:**

How can I get a **copy** of `i` for use in my slot / lambda, so that subsequent iterations of my loop don't change the value in all previous iterations?

Comment: I have run up against this exact problem in the past. you must use a factory function to force i into a local scope. `(lambda a: lambda: print(a))(i)`

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! Funnily enough I just found the exact same solution - as far as I understand the technical term is a `closure`

Comment: re: the solution for the dupe, `functools.partial` is very readable and explicit to the reader what the intent is, and is therefore the best solution imao (code is read much more often than it's written ;)

Comment: @SteveLorimer The usual solution for `lambda` to make use of default arguments: `connect(lambda *args, i=i: print(i))`.

Comment: @SteveLorimer the issue, specifically, is that python (as it works in most modern languages) uses *lexical scoping*.  The functions you are passing in are closed over `i`, they always refer to the `i` where they were defined. That `i` will forever be the last `i` in the loop. It's not about copying objects, you only copy objects, not variables.